# RSelenium not opening browser

Tags: r, google-chrome, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to simply open a browser with RSelenium with the following code:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- rsDriver(
  port = 4446L,
  browser = "chrome",
  chromever =  "87.0.4280.88"
)
remDr$open()
```

I am receiving the following error:

> Selenium message:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
> Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
> System info:os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '15.0.1'
> Driver info: driver.version: unknown

> Could not open chrome browser.
> Client error message:
> Summary: UnknownError
> Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command
> Further Details: run errorDetails method
> Check server log for further details.

I have checked and my chrome version is the following: Version 87.0.4280.141. When I run binman::list_versions("chromedriver"), I have the following versions available "87.0.4280.88" "88.0.4324.27". I have tried both of these versions in the script above but I receive the same error. I am not sure what else to try so if anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. I am running this on a Mac.

Comment: Did you try firefox?

Comment: I was having the same problem today. Similar configuration. Same error message. Using firefox solved my problem!